# Como mostrar anúncios intersticiais depois de carregar a tela inicial?

Tags: java, android, admob

Preciso de ajuda, eu gostaria de exibir um anúncio intersticial após a tela inicial carregar, mas meu código está dando a seguinte falha:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: isLoaded must be called on the main UI thread.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        // FIREBASE INTERSTICIAL
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2565065222479596/3931476543");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        Toast.makeText(this,"* Necessário Acesso a Internet *",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        timerThread.start();

    }

    // FIREBASE INTERSTICIAL
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

DEBUG:

```
    01-22 16:27:03.048 13840-13970/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: idea.tisco.pepavideos, PID: 13840
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: isLoaded must be called on the main UI thread.
    at oc.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951448:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.d(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951448:98)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ak.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951448:14)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzep$zza$zza.isReady(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfa.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
    at company.ts.SplashScreenActivity$2.run(SplashScreenActivity.java:50)
```

Mesmo após a depuração, não consegui entender o motivo do erro.

Gostaria apenas de exibir um intersticial logo após a tela inicial ou quando eu abrir a atividade principal.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Vale a pena lembrar que começar um interstitial logo após a abertura da tela inicial fere as regras do Google. Você pode ter sua conta suspensa por causa disso.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=pt-BR&ref_topic=2745287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você cria uma `thread` no Android, você **não** pode modificar a `thread` de interface do usuário diretamente. É necessário utilizar o método [**runOnUiThread**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Dessa forma:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
});
```

E para carregar o `InterstitialAd`, basta adicionar o código abaixo no seu método `onCreate`

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2565065222479596/3931476543");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Comment: Obrigado Valdeir. Funcionou, não apareceu mais o erro.
Mas não sei pq o interticial não apareceu, ele sempre cai no else.

Comment: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else
                                {}

Comment: Como o banner ainda não foi carregado a condição `if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {` sempre será falsa. Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Valdeir.
Perfeito!!!
Obrigado por contribuir com seu conhecimento, me ajudou demais.
Abraço!